# Understanding peak frequency and frequency response

Tags: control-theory

I am reading a book about control and I am having trouble understanding a paragraph. It says that the peak frequency should not be too big because then certain frequencies will dominate and the system will become slingy.
Could someone give a practical example as to what that means. My understanding is that we must choose a certain frequency we want to our input to have. Am I wrong? Do we look at all the frequencies. I feel I have mixed up stuff in my head.

Comment: I assume the book is talking about resonance?

Comment: Also did the book itself used the term slingy? If not, could you maybe explain a bit more in your question what you mean by this?

Comment: Peak frequency of what? There is no real system whose input consists of a single frequency.